# Boost linking fail

Tags: c++, file, boost, linker

I have the following code which i m trying to compile:

```
#include <boost/filesystem/convenience.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
    namespace bf = boost::filesystem;
    BOOST_FOREACH(bf::path path,
            boost::make_iterator_range(
                bf::recursive_directory_iterator(bf::path("/home")),
                bf::recursive_directory_iterator())) {
        std::cout << path.string() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My boost library is in /home/foo/include . and the include files are actually there.

when i run the following:

```
g++ -I/home/foo/include/ test.cc
```

I get the following error. how can i resolve this. what should i follow?

```
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.text+0x502): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.text+0x51b): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.text+0x534): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.text+0x54d): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.text+0x566): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost10filesystem24basic_directory_iteratorINS0_10basic_pathISsNS0_11path_traitsEEEE6m_initERKS4_+0x2e): In function `boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::m_init(boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&)':
: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::not_found_error()'
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost10filesystem24basic_directory_iteratorINS0_10basic_pathISsNS0_11path_traitsEEEE6m_initERKS4_+0xbe): In function `boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::m_init(boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&)':
: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_first(void*&, void*&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::filesystem::file_status&, boost::filesystem::file_status&)'
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC1Ev+0x14): In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost10filesystem24basic_directory_iteratorINS0_10basic_pathISsNS0_11path_traitsEEEE9incrementEv+0xde): In function `boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::increment()':
: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_increment(void*&, void*&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::filesystem::file_status&, boost::filesystem::file_status&)'
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost10filesystem6statusINS0_10basic_pathISsNS0_11path_traitsEEEEENS_9enable_ifINS0_13is_basic_pathIT_EENS0_11file_statusEE4typeERKS7_+0x34): In function `boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::is_basic_path<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, boost::filesystem::file_status>::type boost::filesystem::status<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >(boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&)':
: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status_api(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::system::error_code&)'
/tmp/ccvDmFNL.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost10filesystem6detail11dir_itr_impINS0_10basic_pathISsNS0_11path_traitsEEEED1Ev+0x1d): In function `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::~dir_itr_imp()':
: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**EDIT:**

Now i tried:

```
g++ -I/home/foo/include/ test.cc -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

and get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have the libboost_system-gcc34-1_38.so within

```
/home/foo/lib
```

how can I point to that?

Comment: I added an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35732953/984260). The answers below did not work for me, although they may be achieving the same thing which I did.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

from gcc man page:

`-Ldir Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l.`

So, is it that you are missing `-L/home/foo/lib` to the command line?

Your code compiled properly on my linux machine (Ubuntu 10.04, boost-filesystem 1.40) with the following command:

`g++ test.cpp  -lboost_filesystem`

or

`g++ test.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem`

It gave me compile errors with `g++ test.cpp -lboost_system`

Comment: `boost_filesystem.so` has an auto-dep on `boost_system.so`? I need to rtfm more often.

Answer (score 2):

You must tell the compiler/linker where your libraries are as well, if they are not in the default location. For this you must use the `-L` flag to the compiler:

```
g++ -I/home/y/include/ test.cc -L/home/foo/lib -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `-lboost_system` (`-lboost_system-mt` if you're going to be threading) and `-lboost_filesystem` (`-lboost_filesystem-mt` if you're going to be threading) to the cmdline, before any input files.

Comment: I m getting this now: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status . I have libboost_system-gcc34-1_38.so in /home/foo/lib . can i use that? how can i link to that?

Comment: Add `-L/home/foo/lib` before `lboost_...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your boost libraries appear to be decorated with the suffix gcc34-1_38.  Are you using gcc 3.4?  Is your boost library on the library path?  If not you may need to add the the path to your boost libraries using the `-L` flag to g++ or you can add the path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.  In any case, you can link to your boost libraries by using `-lboost_system-gcc34-1_38` and `-lboost_filesystem-gcc34-1_38`.