# Linking boost::filesystem on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cmake

I am trying to link a project to boost:filesystem on Ubuntu 13.04 and I am geting some weird linking errors in the last stage.

The build configuration is done via cmake:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem program_options REQUIRED )
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

target_link_libraries(${YARS_TARGET} yarsLib GLEW GL GLU glut m dl xerces-c ode ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

I tried using a different boost version. For 1.49 and 1.53 I have the same behaviour.
On Ubuntu 12.04 it does work just dine and on my development machine running Archlinux with boost 1.53 it compiles, links and runs just fine.

```
/usr/bin/g++   -O3    CMakeFiles/yars.dir/yarsMain.o  -o ../bin/yars  
-L/home/vagrant/local/lib -rdynamic ../lib/libyarsLib.a -lGLEW -lGL -lGLU 
-lglut -lm -ldl -lxerces-c -lode -lboost_system 
-lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options 
../lib/libsensorLib.a ../lib/libenvironmentLib.a ../lib/libutilLib.a ../lib/libutilFilterLib.a ../lib/libutilFormatLib.a ../lib/libutilFunctionGeneratorLib.a ../lib/libutilIoLib.a ../lib/libutilMathLib.a ../lib/libutilDefineLib.a ../lib/libdescriptionLib.a ../lib/libfilterDescriptionLib.a ../lib/libfunctionGeneratorDescriptionLib.a ../lib/libfunctionGeneratorDescriptionUtilLib.a ../lib/libbioDescriptionLib.a ../lib/libsensorsDescriptionLib.a ../lib/libyarsDirectoriesModel.a -Wl,-rpath,/home/vagrant/local/lib: 
    ../lib/libutilIoLib.a(FileSystemOperations.o):
In function `FileSystemOperations::doesDirExist(boost::filesystem::path)':
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    ../lib/libutilIoLib.a(FileSystemOperations.o): In function `FileSystemOperations::doesFileExist(boost::filesystem::path)':
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    ../lib/libutilIoLib.a(FileSystemOperations.o): In function `FileSystemOperations::doesDirExist(std::string*)':
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    ../lib/libutilIoLib.a(FileSystemOperations.o):FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0xdf): more undefined references to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)' follow
    ../lib/libutilIoLib.a(FileSystemOperations.o): In function `FileSystemOperations::getFirstExistingDirContainingDir(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >, std::string*)':
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::root_directory() const'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x35e): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x373): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x403): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x453): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x50d): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x564): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    ../lib/libutilIoLib.a(FileSystemOperations.o): In function `FileSystemOperations::getFirstExistingDirContainingFile(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >, std::string*)':
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x7e3): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::root_directory() const'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x87e): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x893): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x923): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x95b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x973): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0xa2d): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0xa84): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    ../lib/libutilIoLib.a(FileSystemOperations.o): In function `FileSystemOperations::getFirstExistingDir(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >)':
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0xd53): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    ../lib/libutilIoLib.a(FileSystemOperations.o):FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0xd68): more undefined references to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)' follow
    ../lib/libutilIoLib.a(FileSystemOperations.o): In function `FileSystemOperations::checkValidPath(std::string*, bool, bool, std::string)':
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x1100): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::initial_path(boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x1124): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x11e9): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::root_directory() const'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x1237): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x130a): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x131f): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x137b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::system_complete(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x13dc): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    ../lib/libutilIoLib.a(FileSystemOperations.o): In function `FileSystemOperations::checkValidPathFromAlternatives(std::string*, std::string*, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >*, bool, std::string)':
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x1635): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::root_directory() const'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x1699): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x16d0): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::system_complete(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    FileSystemOperations.cpp:(.text+0x173f): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a suggestion:

1)Check that your boost library contains required symbols, you can use something like this:
nm -D /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.52.0 | grep detail | c++filt | grep your names

2)Try to change order of linking library, for example put -lboost_bla-bla-bla to the end of command line, and run this command with g++ again, not use make or something, just copy paste command and make experiments with it.

Comment: that leaves me now slightly baffled. The second one worked any idea why?

Comment: The simple vision for that is when linker try to resolve symbol it can not find one, because of this library not handled yet. Ordinary you don't see this issues, because of  the most of libraries are shared, so the symbol resolution different from resolution for static archives.

Comment: linking order with gcc is always interesting.  Do you think you can post more detail about the CMakeLists.txt, specifically what ${YARS_TARGET} is?

Comment: Also very curious, do you get different behavior when you specify the boost components in a different order?

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem program_options REQUIRED )

Answer (score 0):

I was facing errors like:

```
filename.cpp:(.text+0x389): undefined reference to boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
filename.cpp:(.text+0x39c): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
obj/x86_64/release/filename.cpp.o: In function `readFromFileNotForm(boost::filesystem::path&, char*, unsigned int)':
filename.cpp:(.text+0x1291): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
obj/x86_64/release/filename.cpp.o: In function `readFromFileForm(boost::filesystem::path&, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&)':
filename.cpp:(.text+0x167a): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
```

Other solutions did not work. I wrote this in my cpp file:

```
#include "boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp"
```

And the problem went away. I guess, it was not able to include it automatically. I also tried with v2, but that did not work, I had to do v3.