# How to use Boost Wave Lib on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost

### Heading

I am trying to use Boost Wave, but I fail to compile it with those samples in `boost_1_55_0/lib/wave/samples`. The system I am using is Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

For examples, when I try to compile the `quick_start.cpp` I use the commend:

```
c++ -I ~/Documents/boost_1_55_0 quick_start.cpp -o parser \
~/Documents/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_wave.a
```

The `libboost_wave.a` is what I get from the `./b2` build commend of boost. The compile output is a super long result ending with:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Part of the rest of output looks like(they are so long):

```
/tmp/ccpBhjhs.o: In function `boost::filesystem::operator!=(boost::filesystem::path
const&, boost::filesystem::path const&)':
quick_start.cpp:     (.text._ZN5boost10filesystemneERKNS0_4pathES3_[boost::filesystem::operator!=(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&)]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::compare(boost::filesystem::path const&) const'
/tmp/ccpBhjhs.o: In function `boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*)':
```

I have no clue what happened! Thanks for reading! If you can help me, Please!

p.s.  I have built the wave library following the steps on [Boost Website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#build-a-simple-program-using-boost). I managed to use the regex library to build the sample e-mail extract program. So I think my wave library is built correctly.

Comment: link `boost_filesystem` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the suggestions in this link:

[Linking boost::filesystem on Ubuntu 13.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560057/linking-boostfilesystem-on-ubuntu-13-04)

1) Check that your boost library contains required symbols, you can use something like this: `nm -D /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.52.0 | grep detail | c++filt | grep your names`

2) Try to change order of linking library, for example put `-lboost_bla-bla-bla` to the end of command line, and run this command with g++ again, not use make or something, just copy paste command and make experiments with it.

3) And, of course, make sure you have a "libboost_filesystem.XXX" (either a static .a or shared .so library), and make sure it's in your "ld" (link) command.